# Creating a client in ruby, what are the fastest json parsing options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I have a Java based service that exposes its API using JSON.

1. From a rails application, do I need to create these ruby objects by hand and then serialize/deserialize or will it pickup the properties automatically like ActiveRecord does?
2. Since I am consuming this JSON api myself, and it is uses in a web application, I want the serialization/deserialization to be done as fast as possible, even if it means more coding b/c this is a high traffic application.  What options are there in Ruby?

Comment: Use something C-based, e.g. https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby

Answer (score 0):

I am working with a rails app that consumes many resources from a JAVA Rest API. Using [ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) is fast and clean, and you don't have to implement the object types in your application